# React client side Google api Calendar 403

Tags: reactjs, google-api, auth0, google-workspace

I have this working on local host and events are pulled through from Google Calendar. When i deploy and test the calendar integration it fails with a 403 :

```
domain: "global", message: "The request is missing a valid API key.", reason: "forbidden"
```

Everything is server side and I have attempted to use Auth0 for login (which works perfectly), but then extend that authentication to Google calendar. It seemed to be working until I deployed!

React function runs on component mount:

```
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {

            gapi.client.init({
                apikey: API_KEY,
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                scope: SCOPES,
            })

            gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('Loaded Calendar v3'))
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().then(() => {...
```

Comment: Are the constants like ```API_KEY``` coming from environment variables? Depending on where you have it deployed, you may need to add env variables in your dashboard (like on Heroku)

Comment: You could also ```console.log(API_KEY)``` before calling ```gapi.client.init()``` as a sanity check

Comment: No I have them hard coded for now so I know they are being passed through!

Comment: Yeah its there - I wish it was that

Answer (score 0):

I think the capitalization of `apikey` is off, try:

```
gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
})
```

Comment: I will try but I dont think it is an error like this as it works on localhost perfectly but then after being deployed mentions a 403 error.